Tarski-Vaught Test and Elementary Chains
Consider   the following:
If $M_i,i\ge 1$ is a chain of structures so that that $M_i\preceq M_{i+1},\forall \; i\ge 1$ ($\preceq$ meaning "is an elementary substructure"), then for all $i\ge 1$, $M_i \preceq \bigcup M_i$. (Here $ \bigcup M_i$ has  the canonical structure on the union).
This I can prove easliy by induction on the complexity of the formula.
My questions is: Can one deduce this fact from the Tarski-Vaught Test ?

No, at least not directly.
Let $M_\omega = \bigcup_{i\in\omega} M_i$. To apply Tarski-Vaught to show $M_i\preceq M_\omega$, let $\varphi(x,\bar{b})$ be a formula in one free variable $x$ and parameters $\bar{b}$ from $M_i$. Assume $M_\omega\models \exists x\, \varphi(x,\bar{b})$. We must show that there is $a\in M_i$ such that $M_\omega\models \varphi(a,\bar{b})$.
Ok, since $M_\omega\models \exists x\,\varphi(x,\bar{b})$, there is some $c\in M_\omega$ such that $M_\omega\models \varphi(c,\bar{b})$. Since $M_\omega = \bigcup_{j\in \omega} M_j$, there is some $j\in \omega$ such that $c\in M_j$. If $j\leq i$, we're done, taking $a = c$. But if $i < j$, note that we don't know that $M_j\models \varphi(c,\bar{b})$, so there's no way for us to use the hypothesis that $M_i\preceq M_j$. We can't go from $M_\omega\models \varphi(c,\bar{b})$ to $M_j\models\varphi(c,\bar{b})$ without knowing $M_j\preceq M_\omega$, which is what we're trying to prove!
On the other hand, note that to check that $M_\omega$ and $M_i$ agree on the truth of instances of $\exists x\, \varphi(x,\bar{y})$, it would suffice to know that $M_\omega$ and $M_i$ agree on the truth of instances of $\varphi(x,\bar{y})$. This leads to the idea of arguing by induction on complexity of formulas. And going that route leads directly to a proof that doesn't need to use Tarski-Vaught at all.

Thank you very much, this was exactly the problem I was having.
